# How can I apply the Android Oreo(8.0) Autofill framework to WebView?

Tags: android, webview, autofill

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#all-apps

Web form autofill

Now that the Android Autofill Framework provides built-in support for autofill functionality, the following methods related to WebView objects have changed for apps installed on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26):

WebSettings

- The getSaveFormData() method now returns false. Previously, this method returned true instead.
- Calling setSaveFormData() no longer has any effect.

WebViewDatabase

- Calling clearFormData() no longer has any effect.
- The hasFormData() method now returns false. Previously, this method returned true when the form contained data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic example to force an autofill request

```
public void eventHandler(View view) {
    AutofillManager afm = context.getSystemService(AutofillManager.class);
    if (afm != null) {
        afm.requestAutofill();
    }
}
```

check the complete [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html)

Comment: test url :  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autocomplete

Comment: How do you apply the eventHandler() to the Webview exactly?